# Removing specific HTML tag using REGEX on pattern.compile

Tags: java, regex

How can i use regex to get the following. the matter within the tags might be alphabets,numbers & meta characters.

Input Srting : `"<p>Hi </p><p>there</p>"`

Expected output: `"Hi<p>there</p>.`

Comment: What are the rules? Remove first `<p />`? Remove first tag? Remove all tags but not the last one? Remove any tag that contains at least one whitespace? Do the tags can contain attributes (e.g. `style=""`)?

Comment: Unless it's super simple and trivial, do not use regex to parse HTML. Try a HTML parser instead.

Comment: Agree with Bala, unless looking for a particular tag, don't use regex -- it can be quite daunting to do so.  If you are just looking to remove white space before the closing tag, then that is pretty simple.

Comment: [It reminds me something...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1225328)

Answer (score 0):

Until futher specs arrive, use the following:

`<p>(.)*?</p>` and use the first (and only) group (.)*?

This matches `<p> Hi </p>` then use \1 to refference ' Hi '